# ElasticSearch Filtering By Keys of term aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, data-storage, elasticsearch-6

I have an ES query which returns me data in the following format"

```
"by_group": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 55,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 1094497,
    "buckets": [{
        "key": "a838c7df-1ea9-48f1-aa71-69936b54f47d",
        "doc_count": 69,
        "by_subGroup": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                    "key": "k1",
                    "doc_count": 45
                },
                {
                    "key": "k2",
                    "doc_count": 7
                },
                {
                    "key": "k3",
                    "doc_count": 6
                },
                {
                    "key": "k6",
                    "doc_count": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

I would like to filter my result(by_group) using the keys of my subgroup.
for example
I only want the by_group which have keys:k1,k2 but not k3.

Is it possible to filter in this way?

my current query looks like:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
    },
    "aggs": {
            "aggs": {
                "by_group": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "field1",
                        "size": 10
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "by_subGroup": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "field2",
                                "size": 1000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) in aggregation.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
    },
    "aggs": {
            "aggs": {
                "by_group": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "field1",
                        "size": 10
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "by_subGroup": {
                            "filter": {
                                "terms" : {
                                    "field2": ["k1","k2]
                                }
                            },
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "field2",
                                "size": 1000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would give me all groups with field k1 and/or k2, I need to say k1 and k2 and !k3

Comment: Ok. You can alter the filter condition with additional bool query, should query.